# Are state disability benefits taxable in tax year when you were eligible for them, or approved for them, or when benefits were actually paid?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california, benefits

Imagine that someone gave birth on November 5th, 2020. California allows moms to take off up to 8 weeks of [disability insurance benefits](https://www.edd.ca.gov/disability/pfl_mothers.htm#:%7E:text=As%20a%20pregnant%20mom%2C%20you,delivery%20to%20recover%20from%20childbirth.).

**Are such state disability insurance benefits taxable in 1) tax year when you were eligible for them; or 2) approved for them; or 3) when benefits were actually paid?**

P.S. I know that state is supposed to send 1099-G form. But in case some benefits were paid back (e.g. PFL) so you would qualify for DI, then it is hard to figure out if manual adjustments to 1099-G needs to be made in case some benefits were paid back.